# Allowing backorders on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, backorder

Magento 2.0.10, I want to allow customers to order a product when its not in stock (i.e. when the available stock quantity is =< 0). I have set **Allow quantities below 0** but the storefront doesn't show an add to cart button. If I set the product to 'in stock', the add to cart button is shown, but it also displays the product as In Stock. What I need is for the add to cart button to be shown, but the stock status to display as 'out of stock'. Any ideas how I do this?

**Update** - I have now found and edited the `list.phtml & listing.phtml` template files so that the in/out of stock status and the add to cart button is shown, but if the product is out of stock and I add it to the shopping cart, I get a validation error stating that the product is out of stock (and the item is not added to the cart). I must be missing a setting somewhere, otherwise backorders aren't possible in Mag 2, which I don't think is the case. Help.

Comment: Any news about this issue? Why doesn't backorders work?

Answer (score 4):

You have missing Backorder configuration from Admin.
You dont need to customize any changes in template file.

Just set configuration from,

> Stroes -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory

Click on Product stock Options Tab.

```
Now Choose Backorders Value as Allow Qty Below 0.
```

Save.

[image]
Run Command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

Comment: Unfortunately I've already got these settings, but it still doesn't work. Could it be theme related? is so, where would I look?

Comment: Can we enable backorder for b2b customer only ? If yes then how ?

Comment: @DavidSmith did you found any solution

Answer (score 1):

Set positive QTY(1) of product, staus should be enabled and stock should be instock.

So for this product, ADD TO CART button will be appeared now. Place an order of this product by 1 QTY so product will be out of stock. Now check the detail page and this time Add To Cart button will be there instead of Out Of Stock Button.

I don't know why but this works for me. Try with yours

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 has confirmed bug.

Here is GitHub issue: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10304

Also issue contains useful information about workarounds.